# Enabeling "Hide IP address"

Tags: macos, safari, privacy, web-inspector

Safari 15.5 has an option in Preferences/Privacy to "Hide IP address". When turned on, this has led to some web-sites not loading at all or only loading partially. independent.co.uk is an example of a site that does not load. Turning this option off makes the page load.

Opening the Network tab in the Web Inspector (alt+cmd+i) panel reveals that moatads.com and doubleclick.net does not respond and hangs the loading of the page when this option is on.

Testing the same thing on a different network does not give the same result. This makes me think that this issue is caused by the network configuration of my first network.

How would I go forward to investigate what is the cause of this issue? Are there specific requirements for the network configuration to enable this option?

Comment: Sounds like those sites try to detect ad-blockers and see the hide IP address as trying to block.

Comment: I have selected "Hide IP address" with option "from Trackers and Websites" and have no problem with opening cnn.com and independent.co.uk. So it might be something else which causes it.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg Thanks for testing. I did another test when connected to another network, and now it seems to work. I will go back to the first connection tomorrow and see if it was temporary or if it has to do with the first network-configuration.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg I did an update of the question after testing on another network configuration. I guess there are some requirements for this option that is not met in my network configuration. I would like to know what that could be.